# A solution to the AST Typing Problem

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Expression trees are the bread and butter of functional programming but when it comes to adding additional information to an established tree it can be difficult to incorporate such changes without breaking the existing interface. I have attempted to solve the problem with this example which demonstrates two different enhancements with a common evaluation function.

Comments would be appreciated on the overall structure and especially the ASTBuilder instance for ExpLine which currently relies on UndecidableInstances and the definition of removeHoles.

```
> {-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, ViewPatterns,  PatternSynonyms, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, FunctionalDependencies, FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances #-}


> import Control.Monad.State
> import Control.Applicative

The basic parameterised type

> data ExpF a =
>     AddF a a
>   | NumF Int deriving (Show, Functor)
>
> data Exp  = Exp (ExpF Exp) deriving (Show)
> data ExpH = Holey (Either Hole (ExpF ExpH)) deriving (Show)
> data ExpLine = Line Int (ExpF (ExpLine)) deriving (Show)
>
> data Hole = Hole deriving (Show)

View Typeclass. There isn't an instance which makes sense for ExpH

> class ASTView a where
>   view :: a -> ExpF a
>
> instance ASTView Exp where
>   view (Exp x) = x
>
> instance ASTView ExpLine where
>   view (Line _ x) = x

Generic pattern matches - note that we maintain the interface!

> pattern Add a b <- (view -> (AddF a b))
> pattern Num n <- (view -> (NumF n))

Building type class

> class ASTBuild a  where
>   construct :: ExpF a -> a 
>
> instance ASTBuild Exp where
>   construct x = Exp x
>
> instance MonadState Int m => ASTBuild (m ExpLine)  where
>   construct (AddF a b) = do
>     n <- get 
>     a' <- a
>     b' <- b
>     return $ (Line n (AddF a' b'))
>   construct (NumF v) = do
>     n <- get
>     inc 
>     return $ (Line n (NumF v))
>
> inc :: MonadState Int m => m ()
> inc = modify (+1)
>
> instance ASTBuild ExpH where
>   construct = Holey . Right

Generic Constructors, direct drop in for functions in the builder

> add :: ASTBuild f => f -> f  -> f
> add a b = construct (AddF a b)
>
> num :: ASTBuild f => Int -> f
> num n = construct (NumF n)

Examples 

1. Normal

> example1 :: Exp
> example1 = (num 5) `add` (num 6)

2. Holey - Allows you to leave holes in the structure to fill in later.
This could be a direct replacement to the fmonad.

> holeExample :: ExpH
> holeExample = add (num 6) hole
>
> example2 :: Exp
> example2 = removeHoles holeExample
>
> hole :: ExpH
> hole = Holey (Left Hole)
>
> removeHoles :: ExpH -> Exp
> removeHoles (Holey (Left Hole)) = num 5
> removeHoles (Holey (Right k)) = recurse removeHoles k

> -- This is a fold
> recurse :: (a -> Exp) -> ExpF a -> Exp
> recurse f (AddF e1 e2) = add (f e1) (f e2)
> recurse _ (NumF n) = num n

3. Adding additional information is also easy, this example labels each leaf with a unique number. Could be used for attrs on every node or keeping track of line numbers.

> leafCounter :: State Int ExpLine
> leafCounter = add (num 5) (num 6)
>
> example3 :: ExpLine
> example3 = evalState leafCounter 0

All 3 examples are then evaluated with the same function

> eval :: (ASTView v) => v -> Int
> eval (Add a b) = eval a + eval b
> eval (Num n) = n
>
> main :: IO ()
> main = 
>   do
>     print (eval example1) 
>     print (eval example2) 
>     print (eval example3)
```

Comment: It's been three years. Do you want to review your own code?